# Javascript get result array from two input arrays

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I have two arrays

```
a=[2,3 ,10, 20] 

b=[true, false, false, true]
```

the final result should be

```
result=[2,20]
```

that is a where b is true

how can do this using javascript functional programming (without for loop).

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

> The `filter()` method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

You can use `filter()` on the first array. In side the callback function check the item of the current index from the second array:

```js
let a=[2,3 ,10, 20] 

let b=[true, false, false, true]

let res = a.filter((n,i) => b[i] == true);
//OR:
//let res = a.filter((n,i) => b[i]);
console.log(res);
```